# Trouble converting string/character to byte in lisp

Tags: lisp, babeljs

I've some data that I'm reading in using `read-line` and I want to convert it into a byte-array. `babel:string-to-octet` works for the most part except when the character\byte is larger (above 200) in which case it returns two numbers. As an example, if the character is `ú` using `babel:string-to-octet` returns `(195 185)` instead of `250` which is what I'm looking for. I tried a number of encodings in babel but none of them seem to work.

If I use `read-byte` or `read-sequence` it does read in `250`. But for reasons of backward compatibility, I'm left with using `read-line` and I would like to know if there is something I'm missing when using `babel:string-to-octet` to convert `ú` to `250`.

I'm using ccl 1.8 btw.

Comment: Of course, the moment I ask a question, I find the answer. Using ccl:encode-string-to-octets solved my problems. I'm not sure what the difference is between the ccl and the babel versions. Also not sure if I should delete this question since it has been solved.

Comment: Read up on character encodings, in your case ISO-8859 vs. UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks @starblue. I tried most of those encodings as well but I guess I didn't try ISO-8859-15 which is what finally worked for me using babel.

Answer (score -1):

There are more than 256 characters supported by most common-lisp implementations.  By the pigeonhole principle, that means you can't convert all characters to a single byte.

If you just want to convert the lisp internal character codes 0-255 to bytes, than char-code will do what you want.  However, the result will be implementation defined, as implementations are not required to use any particular encoding internally.